# Confused about some WPF toolkit source code

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, toolkit

I was reading WPF toolkit's source code, and I found in the Toolkit project,
every control was written in two folders named :Implementation and Themes.

Like this:
- WatermarkTextBox
    -- Implementation
       WatermarkTextBox.cs
    -- Themes
       Generic.xaml

By doing this, the control can apply to the Theme by default.
By when I delete the Generic.xaml, the Visual Studio get en error to find the Generic.xaml file.

So, I'm confused about this pattern, is this a pattern supported by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `CustomControl` in WPF, you should put your default `Style` into a file named `Generic.xaml`. The Framework looks into this file to find default `Style`s for all `CustomControl` objects and will give you that error if the file is missing.

You can find a fuller description from the 'Define and Use Shared Resources' section of the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) page at MSDN.

You can find more exact help with creating a `CustomControl` from the [Try it: Create a custom WPF control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: But when I write a control like what toolkit done, nothing happens.And I have tested what you told me, if I delete the Generic.xaml, there is no error, just the style is not applied.

Comment: Sorry, I found the Generic.xaml written by toolkit, in the Themes foloder, you are right, they add the xaml in the Generic.xaml, so when i delete that file, error came out.

Comment: If you follow all of the advice in the linked Microsoft pages (I added another one for you), then you will fix your problems. You could have any number of problems with your code and without seeing it, nobody but you can tell. However, this question has now been answered so please mark it as so. If you want to ask a more specific question regarding your code then please add a new question and provide as much code is relevant in that question.

Comment: Glad I could help... take a look at the second link that I provided as well... it's very useful.